# Finding independent transformations using the Jacobian

Tags: probability

I have the question
[image]

This is my current attempt to solve it, but I'm not sure if I'm approaching it right and needed some guidance...

$$z =ax + by$$
$$w =cx + dy$$
Let $\alpha z+\beta w = 0$
$$\alpha(ax+by) + \beta(cx+dy) = 0$$
$$\alpha ax + \alpha by + \beta cx + \beta dy = 0$$
$$x(\alpha a + \beta c) + y(\alpha b + \beta d) = 0$$

$\alpha a + \beta c = 0  \Rightarrow \alpha ba + \beta bc = 0$
$\alpha b + \beta d = 0 \Rightarrow -ab\alpha + (-a)d\beta = 0$
Thus, $\beta(bc-da) = 0 $ and because $bc - ad \ne 0$, then $\beta = 0$

Now $$da\alpha + \beta cd = 0$$
$$-cb\alpha + -\beta cd = 0$$
$$\alpha(ad - bc) = 0$$
Thus $\alpha = 0$ because $ad-bc \ne 0$

Hence, $ad-bc \ne 0$ for $w$ and $z$ to be independent

Comment: Not quite following the calculation part. One could always use the Jacobian transformation and check the condition which lead to independence from the joint pdf. Or a short cut: Note that $(X, Y)$ jointly follows a bivariate normal, so $(Z, W)$ also follows a bivariate normal as they are an affine transform from $(X, Y)$. A pair of bivariate normal is independent if and only if their covariance is $0$. Since $Cov[Z, W] = ac\sigma^2 + bd\sigma^2 + \rho ad\sigma^2 + \rho bc\sigma^2$ and $\sigma^2 > 0$, $Cov[Z, W] = 0 \iff ac + bd + \rho(ad + bc) = 0$